# Interacting with the Wikipedia API

Tags: php, json, wikipedia

Here's a link to get the intro for an article on Wikipedia about Goldman Sachs.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Goldman_Sachs&format=json&exintro=1
```

I have a two part question.

1. How can I use PHP to run these kinds of API calls on the server side? I want to be able to hook up to the Wikipedia API for data on subjects, companies, people without using links
2. How can I parse the JSON or XML so the output will be strictly text?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I use PHP to run these kinds of API calls on the server side?

I believe [cURL](http://php.net/curl) is the usual option. The manual has [examples](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php). You can also use [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen).

> How can I parse the JSON

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode)